# Unity Error CS1520: Method must have a return type

Tags: unity-game-engine, if-statement

I'm trying to trigger the transition from an idle animation to a running animation when the "d" button is being pressed.

(A link to a tutorial covering a transition like this could also work).

```cpp
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

        public class IdleToJump : MonoBehaviour
    {
        bool keyHold = false;
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (keyHold == true)
        {
            anim.Play("Run_Anim");
        }
    }

    private void Key_up(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Key key = (Key)sender;
        if (key == "d") {
            keyHold = false;
        }
        }

        private void Key_down(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Key key = (Key)sender;
            if (key == "d")
            {
                keyHold = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross-check, you're code with this.
Form1 looks like a constructor that somehow got autogenerated. Just comment it out, and add the last two methods inside the class not outside.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class IdleToJump : MonoBehaviour
    {
        bool keyHold = false;
        //public Form1()//Not sure this constructor is relevant in class, so just comment it
        //{
          //InitializeComponent();
        //}
    
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         if (keyHold == true)
         {
            anim.Play("Run_Anim");
         }
    
    
    private void Key_up(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Key key = (Key)sender;
        if (key == "d") {
            keyHold = false;
        }
    }
    
    private void Key_down(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
            Key key = (Key)sender;
            if (key == "d")
            {
                keyHold = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```